# Loaded JARs in spark-shell, but can't reference the variables in the code

Tags: scala, jar, apache-spark

I'm studying Advanced Analytics with Spark.

Here's what happens: I follow the tutorial on `spark-shell`, and I put pretty long lines of codes into it. When I close the lid of my laptop, this puts my laptop to a sleep mode, and when I turn it back on, the codes are gone.

As a solution, as suggested in the book, I am trying to put my code in a `.scala` file, and compile and load it with `JAR` whenever I restart `spark-shell`. The book even provides a simple example to do that. https://github.com/sryza/aas/tree/master/simplesparkproject

So I `git clone`ed the project, ran `mvn package`, and ran `spark-shell` with `spark-shell --jars target/simplesparkproject-0.0.1.jar --master local` just as in the direction.

If you see the git repo for this example, the code contains an object `MyApp` with two functions in it.

```
object MyApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("My App"))
    println("num lines: " + countLines(sc, args(0)))
  }

  def countLines(sc: SparkContext, path: String): Long = {
    sc.textFile(path).count()
  }
}
```

From what I understood, this class and the functions should be able to be referenced in `spark-shell` because it was specified for the `--jars` option.

However, when I type `MyApp` on the `spark-shell`,

```
scala> MyApp
<console>:23: error: not found: value MyApp
       MyApp
       ^
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I make this work?

Comment: So how do you import it?

Comment: spark-shell --jars target/simplesparkproject-0.0.1.jar --master local

Comment: How do you import inside shell.

Comment: I didn't import anything inside the shell. All the includes are on the top of the code(if you see the git repo https://github.com/sryza/aas/blob/master/simplesparkproject/src/main/scala/com/cloudera/datascience/MyApp.scala), and thus in the JAR, so I thought I wouldn't need to import again inside the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just import the object and call required methods:

```
import com.cloudera.datascience.MyApp
MyApp.main()
```